# How does Google use social indicators, like +1, to affect its SERPs?

Tags: seo, google-search, facebook, search-results, google-plus

How does Google use social indicators, like +1, to affect its search engine results pages ?

Besides,+1 it may include shares with or without a link.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, [they don't](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2290337/Matt-Cutts-Google-1s-Dont-Lead-to-Higher-Ranking) affect organic search rankings although [plenty of research, study and others](http://moz.com/blog/google-plus-correlations) in the industry have noticed greater visibility for pages that do have shares / +1's on Google+.